# Can we say that $\int_{0}^{1} f (x)\ \mathrm {d}x \geq \frac {1} {2}$?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, riemann-integration

Suppose $f : D \subset \Bbb R \longrightarrow \Bbb R$ be a non-negative non-constant function on $D$ containing $(0,1)$ such that $f (c)=100$ for some $c \in (0,1)$. Then can we say that $$\int_{0}^{1} f (x)\ \mathrm {d}x \geq \frac {1} {2}.$$

I think it is true but can't properly figure out why? Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think this is true. Consider any function with a very sharp slim peak at $x=c$ (i.e. the dirac delta function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(x)=0$ if $x\in (0,1-{1\over{400}}]$, $f(x)=80000x+200-80000$ for $x\geq 1-{1\over{400}}$.

Answer (score 0):

If the function is continuous, consider the function [(on Desmos)](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wuuibopvgl)$$100\exp \big({-10^6(x-0.5)^2} \big).$$

Its integral is approximately $0.177$, which is smaller than $\frac{1}{2}$.

We can get this function from $e^{-(x-0.5)^2}$. Since its maximum is $1$, multiplying by $100$ to get $100e^{-(x-0.5)^2}$ guarantees that the function will reach $100$. Now, we can make the integral as small as we want by $100\exp \big({-a(x-0.5)^2} \big)$ choosing an $a$ large enough.

Comment: It came in a competitive examination for pursuing Research in Mathematics in India known as "NET"  or National Eligibility Test. In this kind of examination how can we get help from "Desmos"??

Comment: How on earth do we know that you are not allowed to use computer? @DebabrataChattopadhyay.

Comment: @DebabrataChattopadhyay. If that's the case, why didn't you just put it in the question?

Comment: In India any such electronic gadget is strictly prohibited inside the examination hall.